# highcharts mutiple columns charts does not display

Tags: javascript, php, highcharts

i want to display highcharts type columns i have followed this example https://www.highcharts.com/demo/column-basic
in my case data is fetched from database

```js
var id = $("input[id='id1']:checked").val();  
                 getAjaxData(id);     
                //});
   var opt = {
                    chart: {
                        renderTo: 'container4',
                        type: 'column'
                    },
                    title: {
                        text: 'abc',
                        x: -20 //center
                    },
                    
                    xAxis: {
                        categories: []
        
                    },
                    yAxis: {
                        title: {
                            text: 'Millions'
                        },
                        plotLines: [{
                                value: 0,
                                width: 1,
                                color: '#808080'
                            }]
                    },
                    tooltip: {
                        headerFormat: '<span style="font-size:11px">{series.name}</span><br>',
                        pointFormat: '<span style="color:{point.color}">{point.name}</span>:<b>{point.y}</b> of total<br/>'
                    },
                    plotOptions: {
                        series: {
                            borderWidth: 0,
                            dataLabels: {
                                enabled: true,
                                format: '{point.y}'
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    legend: {
      itemStyle: {
                
       fontSize:'10px'
      },
      
                        layout: 'vertical',
                        align: 'right',
                        verticalAlign: 'top',
                        
                        floating: true,
                        borderWidth: 1,
                        backgroundColor: ((Highcharts.theme && Highcharts.theme.legendBackgroundColor) || '#FFFFFF'),
                        shadow: true
      
                    },
                    series: []
                };
    function getAjaxData(id) {
                $.getJSON("file.php", {id: id},function(json) {
                    opt.xAxis.categories = json[0]['data']; 
                    opt.series[0] = json[1];
     opt.series[1] = json[2];
                    chart = new Highcharts.Chart(opt);
                }); 
     }
```

but my char is displaying like this 
[image]

i want to display both columns. but here only one columns is displaying. other display if displayed column is switched off. is it problem with displaying or php file. if it is i will provide it also

Comment: Can you log the info within `opt.series` and paste it as well? (if needed with placeholders but I just want to see the series structure)

Comment: sorry did not understand your question?

Comment: You have `opt.series[0] = json[1];
     opt.series[1] = json[2];
                    chart = new Highcharts.Chart(opt);`, I'd like to see what is inside `opt.series` to see if that might be formatted incorrectly

Comment: sorry i cannot paste that here

Comment: Not even with placeholders? I just need to see the series structure (like, all the strings can be "xxx" and all the values can be 0)

Comment: i think php code will explain the series structure as well ?

Comment: it does not because we do not know what the structure of  `json` is. The data inside the chart is causing this behaviour so we should know the structure of said data. That, or the data in column #2 is significantly smaller and therefore not showing up due to the black colored series having values of + 1 million

Comment: solved my problem thanks for pointing out the problem